# django: Strange error on reverse-related field

Tags: django

This is my model

```
class UserAward(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='awards')
    award = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    week = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    year = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    points_gained = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

and when I give this:

`users = User.objects.filter(awards__award='level up', awards__week=prev_wk, awards__year=prev_year).order_by('-profiles__level')`

I get this error:

`Related Field has invalid lookup: year`

If I remove `filter(awards__year=prev_year)` query works fine.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Did you recently add `year` to the model? You'll need to do a database migration to make sure the table also has that column. Otherwise, what is the type and value of `prev_year`?

Comment: prev_year is 2012. Prev_year is actually the year of the previous week. Will do a database migration, although `year` was from the start

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using DateField and storing the year/week separately?

Comment: no special reason. Thought it would be easier for me to debug if I had all values separated because a lot of external scripts run on a weekly basis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
users = User.objects.filter(awards__award='level up').filter(awards__week=prev_wk).filter(awards__year__exact=prev_year).order_by('-profiles__level')
```

basically django uses `__year` to extract the year field from date objects it thought you wanted the year from that field